# Web scraping of real estates [r]

Tags: r, json, xml, web-scraping, rcurl

I would like to automatically collect specific data on a real estate ad website. I have used packages `tidyverse` and `jsonlite` as a starting point. Using these I am able to collect what I am interested in too some extent.

Let's use this estates webpage: https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty

```
# Libraries -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

# Web Page of Estates: https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha

# Select one region
id = 10

A = paste0("https://www.sreality.cz/api/cs/v2/estates?category_main_cb=1&category_type_cb=1&locality_region_id=", id, "&page=")
B= paste("&per_page=40&tms=1583500044717")
C = paste0(A,1,B)
D = fromJSON(C)


Res <- 
  D$`_embedded`$estates %>% 
  mutate(D$`_embedded`$estates$hash_id) %>% 
  as_data_frame()

Res %>% view()
```

This way the `Res` object contains basic information of interest such as price, also using regular expression we can obtain number of rooms etc. However, there is some information I am intereted in missing such as ***Floor number*** (Podlaží), ***Type of ownership*** (Vlastnictví) and others.

Lets loot at one perticular estate

```
Res$hash_id[1]
```

will return estate ID number we can then google for this offer using the ID.

and we will find following page:

https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/2+kk/praha-praha-4-milevska/822296156#img=0&fullscreen=false

Here we can see that information about Floor (Podlaží:5. podlaží) is at disposal.
However, in D object there is no information about Floor (podlaží) nor about 'Vlastnictví' at disposal.
I would like to be able to scrape this information as well about all the estates.
Is there any way how one can do so in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need additional API calls to get your desired data. The new URL for each `hash_id` is

```
https://www.sreality.cz/api/cs/v2/estates/<hash_id>?tms=<timestamp>
```

Consider this workflow

```
mas_url <- "https://www.sreality.cz"

get_links <- function(url, id, page) {
  tmp <- paste0(
    url, 
    "/api/cs/v2/estates?category_main_cb=1&category_type_cb=1&locality_region_id=", id, 
    "&page=", page, 
    "&per_page=40&tms=1583500044717"
  )
  links <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp)$`_embedded`$estates$hash_id
  tms <- as.character(round(as.double(Sys.time())*1000))
  paste0(url, "/api/cs/v2/estates/", links, "?tms=", tms)
}

# I only scraped three websites for test
res <- lapply(get_links(mas_url, 10, 1)[10:12], jsonlite::fromJSON)
```

Each element in the list `res` corresponds to one estate. The information you need can be found at, for example,

```
res[[1L]]$items
```

Output

```
   negotiation                   name   notes                 value currency      type          unit topped
1        FALSE           Celková cena bez DPH             8 950 400       Kc price_czk za nemovitost     NA
2           NA             ID zakázky    NULL                  D401     <NA>    string          <NA>     NA
3           NA            Aktualizace    NULL                  Dnes     <NA>    edited          <NA>   TRUE
4           NA                 Stavba    NULL               Cihlová     <NA>    string          <NA>     NA
5           NA           Stav objektu    NULL            Novostavba     <NA>    string          <NA>     NA
6           NA            Vlastnictví    NULL                Osobní     <NA>    string          <NA>     NA
7           NA       Umístení objektu    NULL          Centrum obce     <NA>    string          <NA>     NA
8           NA                Podlaží    NULL 4. podlaží z celkem 5     <NA>    string          <NA>     NA
9           NA          Užitná plocha    NULL                    77     <NA>      area            m2     NA
10          NA       Plocha podlahová    NULL                    83     <NA>      area            m2     NA
11          NA                 Terasa    NULL                  TRUE     <NA>   boolean          <NA>     NA
12          NA                  Sklep    NULL                  TRUE     <NA>   boolean          <NA>     NA
13          NA                  Garáž    NULL                  TRUE     <NA>   boolean          <NA>     NA
14          NA      Datum nastehování    NULL            30.01.2023     <NA>      date          <NA>     NA
15          NA Datum zahájení prodeje    NULL            01.08.2020     <NA>      date          <NA>     NA
16          NA                  Výtah    NULL                  TRUE     <NA>   boolean          <NA>     NA
```

Comment: Hi, using your approach I am able to do what I need. However, I sometimes come across this error `Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 503`. Do you happen to know how to fix this as well?

Comment: That means the server is not ready to handle your request. This happens probably because you send requests too frequently, Consider introducing some short breaks in-between your requests, something like `Sys.sleep(1)`

Comment: I have come accros another error when using this approach `Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Send failure: Connection was reset`. In this case I have `Sys.sleep(3)` and this still happens. Once again have you ever encoutered this?

Comment: This is likely a network issue. Usually, it will be auto-resolved on a second or third trial. Consider putting your function calls inside a loop, or check this function `purrr::insistently`.